# kendo ui dropdownlist ng-show is not working correctly in ie9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a problem in IE9. I use ng-show for kendo's drop down list, but when the value is false, the drop down list is also visible. Who can help me

```
<select ng-show="isAllowEdit" kendo-drop-down-list style="width: 100%;" k-value-primitive='true' k-ng-model='UPDocument.Year' k-options='ReferenceYearOptions'></select>
```